# Scale div with its content to fit window

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a fixed-size `<div>` with some complex content (including text and background images). This `<div>` has its size hardcoded in pixels (and its content depends on this size, and content positions are hardcoded in pixels as well).

Here is a greatly simplified example: http://jsfiddle.net/dg3kj/.

I need to scale that div and the content inside it, maintaining its aspect ratio, so it fits the window.

A solution that would not require me to manually change `<div>` contents is preferable (it is generated dynamically and is a bunch of very messy legacy code which I would like to avoid touching). JavaScript (jQuery) solutions are OK (including ones that change the generated content — as long as it is done post-factum of generation itself).

I tried to play with `transform: scale()`, but it did not yield satisfactory results. See here: http://jsfiddle.net/sJkLn/1/. (I expect the red background to be not visible — i.e. outermost `<div>` size should not be stretched by the *original* dimensions of scaled down `<div>`.)

Any clues?

Comment: Do you just intend to scale the size of the div or you expect its contents to scale as well?  For example, should all images double in size, etc?

Comment: What if you set your div size variable using % and then adding the width and height using js after load?

Comment: @JamesMontagne: I need to scale the content as well. Updated the question.

Comment: @Michael: Not sure I follow, sorry :-(

Comment: Well if you want you're div to fit the window size make it adjust using a relative size like 100% but you're content needs a fixed size so use javascript to change the 100% to the actual width/height after loading. We might be able to better help you out if we have a http://jsfiddle.net/ example of what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: Can you explain why `transform: scale()` didn't yield satisfactory results?  Also post an example of your code here and if you can provide a fiddle.

Comment: I've added a link to a fiddle to the question. (Without `scale()` so far.)

Comment: @dc5: I've added an example on why `scale()` does not work for me. (I used fixed ratio there — I guess I should be able to figure it out with JS once I get the principle...)

Answer (score 43, accepted):

```js
let outer = document.getElementById('outer'),
        wrapper = document.getElementById('wrap'),
        maxWidth  = outer.clientWidth,
        maxHeight = outer.clientHeight;
window.addEventListener("resize", resize);
resize();
function resize(){let scale,
    width = window.innerWidth,
  height = window.innerHeight,
  isMax = width >= maxWidth && height >= maxHeight;

    scale = Math.min(width/maxWidth, height/maxHeight);
    outer.style.transform = isMax?'':'scale(' + scale + ')';
    wrapper.style.width = isMax?'':maxWidth * scale;
    wrapper.style.height = isMax?'':maxHeight * scale;
}
```

```css
body {
  font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, "Segoe UI", Roboto, "Helvetica Neue", Arial, sans-serif, "Apple Color Emoji", "Segoe UI Emoji", "Segoe UI Symbol", "Noto Color Emoji";
  background: #e6e9f0;
  margin: 10px 0;
}


#wrap {
  position: relative;
  width: 640px;
  height: 480px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
#outer {
  position: relative;
  width: 640px;
  height: 280px;
  background: url('https://source.unsplash.com/random') no-repeat center center;
  transform-origin: 0% 50%;
  border-radius: 10px;
  box-shadow: 0px 3px 25px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  overflow: hidden;
}
#outer:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  -webkit-backdrop-filter: blur(20px);
  backdrop-filter: blur(20px);
}

#profile {
  background: url('https://source.unsplash.com/random/300x300') no-repeat center center;
  position: absolute;
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  bottom: 0;
  margin: 20px;
  border-radius: 100px;
  background-size: contain;
}
#content {
  font-size: 20px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
  bottom: 0;
  margin: 30px 100px;
  color: white;
  text-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
}

#content div:last-child {
  font-size: 15px;
  opacity: 0.7;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrap">
<div id="outer">
  <div id="profile"></div>
  <div id="content">
    <div>Monwell Partee</div>
    <div>UX / UI Designer</div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: It works, thanks! One problem though is that it does not take surrounding paddings and margins into account...

Comment: Glad it works. You should be able to adjust the math to accommodate your layout - I took the short route to a demo using width()/height()

Comment: This is very useful!! However, is there a work around for Firefox?

Comment: Thanks dc5 this is useful!

@PrimalScientist if you notice in the code there're "-webkit-transform", u can replace it to "transform" or add in any other older modern browser support like "-moz-transform"

Comment: This works, but be careful about having percentages in your css. The percentages might then be calculated based on the scaled width instead of the maxWidth (original width).

Comment: I took your answer, and made a simple function that also works without jquery.
`function scaleBasedOnWindow(elm,scale=1){elm.style.transform='scale('+scale/Math.min(elm.clientWidth/window.innerWidth,elm.clientHeight/window.innerHeight)+')';}`

Answer (score 6):

I took the answer from dc5, and put it in a small function that allows you to set the scale based on window.

```
function scaleBasedOnWindow(elm, scale=1, fit=false){
    if(!fit){
        elm.style.transform='scale('+scale/Math.min(elm.clientWidth/window.innerWidth,elm.clientHeight/window.innerHeight)+')';
    }else{
        elm.style.transform='scale('+scale/Math.max(elm.clientWidth/window.innerWidth,elm.clientHeight/window.innerHeight)+')';
    }
}
```

if you want the element to fit, and not get cut off, just change `Math.min` to `Math.max`, or just set the fit parameter of this function to true.

Minified Version:

```
function scaleBasedOnWindow(elm,scale=1,fit){if(!fit){elm.style.transform='scale('+scale/Math.min(elm.clientWidth/window.innerWidth,elm.clientHeight/window.innerHeight)+')';}else{elm.style.transform='scale('+scale/Math.max(elm.clientWidth/window.innerWidth,elm.clientHeight/window.innerHeight)+')';}}
```

Answer (score 1):

In case anyone building an full-screen application of let's say 1920x1080 and wants to perfectly fit in a smaller screen - e.g 1366x768. This is what I did in Vue.js - but can be done with pure js and css - based on answer above - the main importance is that I set the original width and height specifically otherwise it wasn't working for me:

App.vue
(conditional class if lowres exists in localStorage)

```html
    <template>
        <div id="external-app-wrapper" :class="{lowres: isLowRes}">
            <div id="internal-app-wrapper">
                <router-view />
            </div>
        </div>
   </template>
```

```
computed: {

      isLowRes() {
         return localStorage.getItem('lowres') !== null
      }
}
```

scale is calculated as: 1366/1920 and 786/1080

```css
    #external-app-wrapper {
        width: 1920px;
        height: 1080px;
    }

    .lowres #internal-app-wrapper {
        transform-origin: top left;
        transform: scale(0.71145833333, 0.71111111111);
    }
```

router.js
(resolution is optional)

```
       {
            path: '/app/:resolution?',
            name: 'App Home',
            component: () => import('@/components/routes/HomeRoute'),
            meta: {
                title: 'App Home'
            }
        }
```

in HomeRoute.vue I have:

```
        mounted() {
            if (this.$route.params.resolution === 'lowres') {
                localStorage.setItem('lowres', 'true')
                this.$router.push({ path: '/app' })
                this.$router.go()
            } else if (this.$route.params.resolution === 'highres') {
                localStorage.removeItem('lowres')
                this.$router.push({ path: '/app' })
                this.$router.go()
            }
        }
```

so navigating to `/app/lowres` redirects to `/app` and shrinks the whole application
and redirecting to `/app/highres` redirects to `/app` and resolution is back to normal

Hope someone finds it useful :)

Answer (score 1):

Pure JS Based on `dc5`'s answer;
Scales based on `window resize`

```js
let outer = document.getElementById('outer'),
        wrapper = document.getElementById('wrap'),
        maxWidth  = outer.clientWidth,
        maxHeight = outer.clientHeight;
window.addEventListener("resize", resize);
resize();
function resize(){let scale,
    width = window.innerWidth,
  height = window.innerHeight,
  isMax = width >= maxWidth && height >= maxHeight;

    scale = Math.min(width/maxWidth, height/maxHeight);
    outer.style.transform = isMax?'':'scale(' + scale + ')';
    wrapper.style.width = isMax?'':maxWidth * scale;
    wrapper.style.height = isMax?'':maxHeight * scale;
}
```

```css
body {
  font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, "Segoe UI", Roboto, "Helvetica Neue", Arial, sans-serif, "Apple Color Emoji", "Segoe UI Emoji", "Segoe UI Symbol", "Noto Color Emoji";
  background: #e6e9f0;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}


#wrap {
  position: relative;
  width: 640px;
  height: 480px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
#outer {
  position: relative;
  width: 640px;
  height: 280px;
  background: url('https://source.unsplash.com/random') no-repeat center center;
  transform-origin: 0% 50%;
  border-radius: 10px;
  box-shadow: 0px 3px 25px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  overflow: hidden;
  margin-top: 10px;
}
#outer:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  -webkit-backdrop-filter: blur(20px);
  backdrop-filter: blur(20px);
}

#profile {
  background: url('https://source.unsplash.com/random/300x300') no-repeat center center;
  position: absolute;
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  bottom: 0;
  margin: 20px;
  border-radius: 100px;
  background-size: contain;
}
#content {
  font-size: 20px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
  bottom: 0;
  margin: 30px 100px;
  color: white;
  text-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
}

#content div:last-child {
  font-size: 15px;
  opacity: 0.7;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrap">
<div id="outer">
  <div id="profile"></div>
  <div id="content">
    <div>Monwell Partee</div>
    <div>UX / UI Designer</div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -2):

As long as you make the dimensions of the contents % based, then you'll certainly be able to dynamically resize them based on the outer div. Then just use jQuery:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    var newWidth = '300px';
    $('.your-div').css('width', newWidth);
});
```

Comment: Unfortunately, content positions are in pixels too. I've updated the question to clarify this.

Answer (score -2):

If you need to set this dynamically based on the window, you can set the div to a percentage of available window real-estate too.

```
    jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
        var percentChange = .66;
        var newWidth = $(window).width() * percentChange; 
        $('#primary').css('width', newWidth + 'px');
    });
```

Comment: This wouldn't scale div content, unfortunately.

Comment: If anyone is referencing this still.  This comment is incorrect.  Content inside divs simply need to be in flow.

Comment: But OP is stating that the content is not in flow, but a static hard coded content. Thus your solution does not work.

Comment: No, actually, "#outer" is position relative, so it's in flow. Go look at the jsfiddle. Only the child element "text" is out of flow. Either way, the parent element gets height/width hard-coded, so you don't need js to solve most of this problem. All this person has to do is simply set the percentage offset they want as a margin for the child element. Voila; problem solved.