# Centering block on android chrome

Tags: android, html, css, google-chrome, center

I'm having weird issue with displaying of my web page on mobile Chrome.
I have a block centered horizontally and it is displayed just fine on desktop Chrome, but on mobile Chrome it sticks to the left border of the page.

After some research I realized that there is mobile "viewport" which is different from the screen size.
Thus, it is not a simple task to have something centered.

The simplified markup I'm using:

```
<body>
    <div class="block">
    </div>
</body>
```

And the CSS:

```
body {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
}
.block {
    position: relative;
    width: 1024px;
    height: 768px;
    background-color: red;
    top: 44px;
    margin: auto;
}
```

I've tried also centering the block using:

```
left: 50%;
margin-left: -512px;
position: absolute;
```

But that has the same effect.
Also I've tried adding viewport metatag:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

And it does not help either.
My device has 1920x1080 hardware resolution and it does display the page with real width ~1200px or so, but the "device-width" is 640px by default and if I scale the page using multitouch, it still keeps left border at the initial position.

The best possible goal for me would be having the page fixed at some resolution (1200px is just fine and no scale required for my task) and the block to be centered. But I don't see the way to set the "device-width" to the real hardware pixel size and lock the scaling... (I know how to lock the scaling, but it does not help with the resolution and centering).

An example of the page where it can be easily reproduced: http://37.48.93.204/androidtest.htm

It works just fine at desktop Chrome, but has described issue on Android Chrome.

Comment: try to use the scale property of transform as shown in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18750769/scale-div-with-its-content-to-fit-window

Comment: The problem is I don't know exact width and height that would fit the window.
The browser tells me wrong values not matching really visible area.
Thus, I don't know what to scale/resize the div to.

Comment: Does `margin: 0 auto` work? Since you want to center horizontally, you do not need auto on top and bottom.

Comment: It does not because it centers the block inside the body, while body is not taking the full width of the screen.

Comment: Can u uplad the full page somethere?

Comment: Can't upload full page, sorry.

Comment: since you are not able to support some sort of page create a version using JSFiddle or something that will allow us to view your page without guessing. You sadly have shot down all the viable options as of now and it is about to default answer. You may not get a true answer to your question at that point.

Comment: The problem is all answerers try to help with centering the block within the container while that is working perfectly and it is not the problem. The problem is **The container (body) sticking to the left border of the screen and not taking its full width.**

Comment: I've added link to the example page to the post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you're talking about horizontal centering:

The easiest way of centering something within it's container, would be to give it a fixed width, and then use `margin-left: auto;` and `margin-right: auto;`. This will center the element within it's container.

The best approach would be to set a max-width and play with margins as soon as the screen size is large enough.

Create a wide wrapper with the background image (horizontally centered) and limit the content inside that wrapper to a maximum of 1024px. Then let it resize when the screen is narrower then 1024px.

**[DEMO](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/dPzJPX)**

**HTML code example**

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=1224">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="mainblock">
      <div class="topside">
        Top
      </div>
      <div class="content-wrapper">
        <div class="content">
          Content
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="bottomside">
        Bottom
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

**CSS code example**

```
body {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

.mainblock {
  max-width: 1024px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 768px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.content-wrapper {
  background: url('http://lorempixel.com/1224/768/') no-repeat 50% 0;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  max-width: 1024px;
  padding: 0;
}

.content {
  background: salmon;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  min-height: 768px;
  padding: 0;
  max-width: 1024px;
  width: 100%;
}

.topside,
.bottomside {
  max-width: 1024px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: blue;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 1024px) {
  .mainblock, .content-wrapper {
    max-width: 1224px;
  }

  .content {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 1024px;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 2;
  }

}
```

**Edit:**

Also add the viewport resetting meta tag to the `head`-section of your HTML code:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=1224">
```

**Edit 2:**

Created a new demo (http://codepen.io/anon/pen/dPzJPX) and updated the initial answer.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/69890/discussion-on-answer-by-gerrit-bertier-centering-block-on-android-chrome).

Answer (score 1):

To adjust your page properly on the devices with various resolution you should use the [CSS media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries). This way you can make the sizes of your elements dependent on the screen size. For example:

```
/* normal desktop */
.block {
    width: 1024px;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 1023px) /* notebook */
{
    .block {
        width: 800px;
    }
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 793px) /* tablet */
{
    .block {
        width: 600px;
    }
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 479px) /* old smartphone */
{
    .block {
        width: 400px;
    }
}
```

Regarding the centering, it's a bad practice to trick the exact pixels as you try to do. There are more universal and reliable centering methods like Table based layout or Flexible Boxes model. For more information read the article [Vertical centering of elements in HTML](http://www.web-plus-plus.com/Articles/vertical-centering-elements-html).

Comment: The problem is I don't need the sizes dependent on the screen size. The project is a game and the sizes should be fixed. On the desktop I'm just centering the content block on the screen.

Comment: Than most probably you should consider a mobile version of your game for mobile devices. Even if you will somehow solve the centering problem, you sure will face much more complicated issues here.

Comment: The game works just fine besides the centering and the sound.
I know how to resolve the problem with the sound and the only thing that I can't resolve is the centering.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend changing your CSS to be like this for the block:

```
.block {
position: absolute;
width: 200px;
height: 200px;
background-color: red;
top: 50%;
left: 50%;
margin-top: -100px;
margin-left: -100px;
}
```

Whatever the width of your container is, make the `margin-left` equal to half the `width`.

My code above, will center horizontally and vertically on the page.

Like this: http://jsfiddle.net/6x3a4uaL/

Just checked Chrome on my Android Phone and it works fine on the jsFiddle page.

Comment: The problem is not centering the block within the container (body).
The problem is the container having width less than the full screen width.

Comment: Can you not make the width 100%?

Comment: I'm setting it to 100% but the browser does not stretch it to the window.

Answer (score 0):

To center your "block" object, you may try this:

```
.block {
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 30em;
    height: 60em;
    background-color: red;
}
```

Comment: The problem is not centering the block within the container (body).
The problem is the container having width less than the full screen width.

Answer (score 0):

In case you haven't, try using the `<center></center>` tag. I know it is discontinued but it's worth to try. Also, instead of `margin: auto` try `margin: 0px auto`.

Comment: The problem is not centering the block within the container (body).
The problem is the container having width less than the full screen width.

Comment: I would recommend not recommending deprecated tags.. they still work in most cases, but it is not something you should really support.

Answer (score 0):

**CSS**

```
body {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
}
.block {
    display: flex;
    position: relative;
    width: 1024px;
    height: 768px;
    background-color: red;
    top: 44px;
    margin: auto;
}
```

**HTML**

```
 <div class="block">
    </div>
```

Have a look at `flex` property of CSS

Answer (score 0):

I don't see the point of having on body 100% width. You should provide more information or context though.

I tried something http://jsfiddle.net/c5afz9b1/

1. Removed `width: 100%;` from body
2. Just for testing, put borders on both sides of the block to see whether it is being centered or not. And looks like it's working.
3. Depending on your context, try putting `overflow: hidden` on body.

If you provide more info it would be useful for us.

Comment: The block is still aligned to the left instead of being centered horizontally like I try to do.

Comment: I'm opening http://jsfiddle.net/c5afz9b1/embedded/result/ in Mobile Chrome for iOS8 and it's working. Any special version? Particular OS?

Comment: Check the link I've added to the question.

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/t178r76n/2/

This JSFiddle is something I need you to look at. Essentially I changed some code to be more flexible based on what you're providing.

Now the mainblock is your primary element...

```
.mainblock {
    width: 1024px;
    height: 768px;
    position: relative;
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    margin: auto;
}
```

I need your input on this though... I need to know if I'm in left field or rounding home.

Comment: I've added your styles for .mainblock, does not help :( You can't debug this with JSFiddle, because it reproduced only at the fullscreen. http://37.48.93.204/androidtest3.htm

Comment: in your androidtest3.htm change .mainblock to `position:absolute;` then yes or no? how far away am I?

Comment: also.... .mainblock wasn't the ONLY thing I changed.. There are other minor changes that were made you would have to look through everybit to figure out what works,but let's start with mainblock...

Comment: Yes, it seems to do the trick.
Is there any way to do it without "calc" ?

Comment: You can do it without calc, but you risk a few mis-"calc"-ulations... I only used calc because i knew it was flexible. And it also seems your'e not too worried about other browsers that don't support calc. At that point it is really just messing with stuff. You could use the media queries to use specific widths which could help you, but I don't find that being too perfect.

Comment: There are two problems. First of all, the side blocks should be outside the main block, not inside it. Center block should have the size of the main block (1024x768). Also, your solution does resize the center block when the screen width is below the total width of the content. This is not the intended behavior. In this case it should keep the sizes the same, cut the content with the borders of the screen and position the visible part at the middle of the content. My first variant is doing this at desktop browsers.

Answer (score -1):

Every device and browser has a user-agent, you can do specific rules only for chrome android browser. This is one example of what I'm talking about:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

        $(document).ready(function() {

            var userAgent = navigator.userAgent;
            var cssIosURL = '<link href="${contextPath}/css/ios.css" rel="stylesheet">';
            var cssNativeAndroidURL = '<link href="${contextPath}/css/nativeAndroid.css" rel="stylesheet">';
            var cssAndroidChromeURL = '<link href="${contextPath}/css/androidChrome.css" rel="stylesheet">';

            if (userAgent.indexOf('Mac OS') >= 0) {
                if (userAgent.indexOf('Mobile') >= 0) {
                    $('head').append(cssIosURL);
                }
            }

            if (userAgent.indexOf('Android') >= 0) {
                if ((userAgent.indexOf('Firefox') < 0) && (userAgent.indexOf('Chrome') < 0) && (userAgent.indexOf('Opera') < 0)) {
                    $('head').append(cssNativeAndroidURL);
                } else {
                    $('head').append(cssAndroidChromeURL);
                }
            }

        });

    </script>
```

Comment: I know how to do this, however I still don't know what CSS can I apply to make it working properly.